# "Bypass" Operations and Groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

So I recently stumbled on [this (pdf)](http://www.google.co.th/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.utoronto.ca%2Fbarbeau%2Fputnamgp.pdf&ei=lVytU8nMEciJuASK84FY&usg=AFQjCNERc500_xJTg3kxTkaPCekDc3TwYA&bvm=bv.69837884,d.c2E&cad=rja) collection of group theory related Putnam problems. Problem 1978 A-4 defines a "bypass" operation to be a mapping $\circ:S\times S\mapsto S$ such that

$$(w\circ x)\circ(y\circ z) = w\circ z.$$

I was curious as to whether any groups could be constructed using this as the group operation. I have a proof that $\circ$ is associative, and that any group $G$ with $\circ$ as the group operation must be identical to the trivial group. I was wondering if someone could verify that my proofs are sound. I am open to any and all criticism. Thanks!

Theorem: $\circ$ is associative.

Proof: Let $a,b,c,d,e,f\in S$. Then:
\begin{align}
\notag ((a\circ b)\circ (c\circ d))\circ (e\circ f) &= (a\circ d)\circ (e\circ f)\\ 
\notag &= a\circ f\\
\notag &= (a\circ b)\circ (c\circ f)\\ 
\notag &= (a\circ b)\circ ((c\circ d)\circ (e\circ f))
\end{align}
Thus $\circ$ is associative.

Theorem: Any group $G$ with $\circ$ as the group operation is identical to the trivial group.

Proof: Let $x\in G$. Then, $G$ contains an identity element $1_G$, and as $\circ$ is associative we have:

$$x = x\circ 1_G = (1_G\circ x)\circ(1_G\circ 1_G) = (1_G\circ 1_G) = 1_G$$

by the defining property of $\circ$. Therefore, $G = \{1_G\}$.

Comment: This is very similar to a rectangular band in semigroup theory. A *[rectangular band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_%28mathematics%29#Rectangular_bands)* is a semigroup $S$ where $xyz=xz$ for all $x, y, z\in S$. (Certainly, every rectangular band satisfies your condition, but I do not know if there are semigroups which are not rectangular bands where this condition holds.)

Comment: @user1729PhD Very interesting, it is nice to see that there are non-trivial structures with an operation like this. I was hoping $(G,\circ)$ wouldn't be trivial, but I guess there is too much structure in groups to allow it (if my proof isn't flawed). Do you have any reference suggestions for semigroups? Strange operations like this are actually pretty fun to investigate.